# How to update selected text along with value in knockout bound dropdown list

Tags: knockout.js

My dropdown HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select id="gender" class="form-control"
            data-bind="
            value: gender.id(),
            options: $root.genders,
            optionsText: 'name',
            optionsCaption:'Select ...',
            optionsValue:'id' ">
    </select>
</div>
```

My viewmodel:

```
//
//Child class
//
var child = function(c){
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(c.id);
    self.first_name = ko.observable(c.first_name);
    self.last_name = ko.observable(c.last_name);
    self.gender_id = ko.observable(c.gender_id);
    self.birthday= ko.observable(c.birthday);
    self.family_id = ko.observable(c.family_id);
    self.gender = {
        id: ko.observable(c.gender.id),
        name: ko.observable(c.gender.name)
    }
}

//
// Children viewmodel
//
var childrenViewModel = function(initialData){
    var self = this;
    //
    self.child = ko.observable();
    //
    self.children = ko.observableArray(initialData.map(function(c){
        return new child(c);
    }));
    self.genders = ko.observableArray();
    //
};
```

the problem is that when i change the option in the dropdown list then child 's gender id is only updated not the name property.

I tried binding also `text` to `gender.name()` with no luck

The genders observable:

```
"genders": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Male"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Female"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Other"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: make a sample fiddle so we can play around and will be easy to get you a answer . cheers

Comment: having difficulties in doing so..trying

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/s4m4kthh/

Comment: @haim770: could you elaborate a little on the logic? :)

Comment: If you have a lookup list of `genders`, any entity (`child` for example) that is having an associated `gender` needs to have that association modeled using a **reference** rather than copying the `gender` value-object for each entity. It's still convenient to have the full `gender` object available for you for each entity as well, yet, in my example it's being done used a **computed** function that retrieves the *reference* to the appropriate `gender` using the `gender_id`.

Comment: @haim770: i woudl like a solution that woudl maintain a separate gender object under child, as this is the way that it comes from backend api (laravel)...

Comment: @e4rthdog, The implementation in my Fiddle *will* output your desired format which will include the `gender` object. You can see it in the `<textarea>`.

Comment: What confuses me is that the child is populated from an observablearray of child() which has the gender object nested. This is the way that is fetched. I am populating self.child from a member of the observablearray...

Answer (score 1):

In option value use **$data** instead of **id**. It binds data do **gender_id** and your select box should be like this:

```
<select id="gender" class="form-control"
    data-bind="value: gender_id,
    options: $root.genders,
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsCaption:'Select ...',
    optionsValue:$data ">
</select
```